# How is IP restricted to forwarding on spanning trees?

Tags: networking

[Networking Named Content](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1658941) -

> Machines today typically have multiple
>   network interfaces and are
>   increasingly mobile. Since IP is
>   restricted to forwarding on spanning
>   trees, it is difficult for IP to take
>   advantage of more than one interface
>   or adapt to the changes produced by
>   rapid mobility. CCN packets cannot
>   loop so CCN can take full advantage of
>   mul- tiple interfaces.

I am unaware of IP's restriction on forwarding on spanning trees. Can anyone elucidate on this point and how this restriction seems to not allow IP to take advantage of multiple interfaces on a single machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic assumption is that at any given time, IP networks *must* choose one and only one forwarding tree of nodes to forward IP packets through. If an IP packet ever loops through the same routed node twice in the same forwarding context (1), this is an error and it is the reason all IP packets carry a [TTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) field.  The authors are not using Spanning tree in the sense it's commonly used in the ethernet world... such as the [spanning-tree protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol).

The proposition is that CCN traffic does not have this same forwarding restriction as IP, because forwarding is based on content addresses as opposed to IP addresses.

Thank you for asking, I had not heard of CCN before and this is an opportunity to learn something new.

[Link to the CCN paper if you don't have an ACM subscription](http://ecs.victoria.ac.nz/twiki/pub/Courses/NWEN403_2011T1/LectureSchedule/CCN.pdf)

End note:

1. In this case, I exclude MPLS, GRE, IP-Sec, or other tunneled traffic as being in the same forwarding context